# iPad master detail storyboard setup without uiSplitView

Tags: ipad, storyboard, master-detail, uisplitview

I like the default iPad Master-Detail app in portrait mode (with popoverView) but not in landscape (with splitView).  What's the best way to setup an app so that it have the standard master-detail popoverView appearance even in landscape.  When I seque via bar button to a "Master" sized view the view has tabbed appearance and is styled to eminate from the button, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it's a little more complicated than I thought ,,, but there is an excellent GitHub project which implements exactly what I wanted.
https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController